# How to append input file type value for another input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a problem. I would like to pass the name of the file loaded by the input file type to another in a text box - text type, so that the file name to style somewhat attractive ... this is my code, and thx for help.

```
<fieldset>
    <label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="file_name_field">
    </label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <input type="file" value="wybierz plik " class="add_file_field">
    <span>przeglądaj</span>
</fieldset>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fileName = $('.add_file_field').val();
    $('.file_name_field').val().replace(fileName);
});
```

Comment: Add the HTML snippet please

Comment: $('.file_name_field').val(fileName) it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
 $('.add_file_field').change(function(){
  $('.file_name_field').val($(this).val());
 });
});
```

Comment: Don't overcomplicate things and don't make them intentionally slow. Line 3 in the answer should be at least `$('.file_name_field').val(this.value)` Don't overuse jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Replacing my initial answer: I misunderstood the nature of your problem.

.val() is typical of jQuery functions in that it is a getter and a setter in one. So .val() without a parameter returns the value attribute of the selected element, and to set that attribute, you call .val(newValue).

Your call above gets the string object from the value attribute, then replaces it with a new string, and then the string disappears because you don't assign it anywhere.